# Convert CSV data into fixed width records using PHP and php-excel-reader class

Tags: php, excel, csv, fixed-length-record

My end result is to have a fixed length record created from either a csv of excel file using PHP. I have am working with excel_reader2.php and seems to import this nicely and displays it in the browser. I would like in turn to export or write the contents to a file so that each column would export as 35 characters fixed length fields . currently the $data is formatted as html and dont know how to write down what i am describing. Thank you in advance for someone to point me in the correct direction.

Comment: So you're saying that you have a HTML table as input and you want to display it as plain text with each cell exactly 35 characters wide?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/ is what i am using to display the output of the excel to a browser. what i need is to redirect the same output to a fixed length file with each field 35 characters in length. the <?php echo $data->dump(true,true);?> contains the entire html dump

Comment: Well, if the class allows you to access rows and columns of a sheet, you can loop over them and output the formatted data as described by @Keenora.

Answer (score 2):

You would take every row of the CSV file. Then, every column of the row. For every cell you could use:

```
$newcell = sprintf("[%35s]\n", $cell);
```

So you would have a 35 chars width string with the data of $cell. And then, just add it via two loops into a file.

Comment: Btw. I dunno this excel_reader2.php but if you can get an array, you also could use fputcsv function to write the new csv. http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/ is what i am using to display the output of the excel to a browser. what i need is to redirect the same output to a fixed length file with each field 35 characters in length. the <?php echo $data->dump(true,true);?> contains the entire html dump

Comment: As I said, you only need to get every row and every column, iterate through it and do the sprintf as above on every cell. Then save the new data to a file. Then you will get a fixed length column file.